# comments in sql server, good or not good for performance?

Tags: sql-server

Is it a good practice to add comments on tables and columns via sp_addextendedproperty ?
Someone told me that it will slow the database and it is not worth it.
What do you think ?

Comment: Also see [Performance Implications of Comments in SQL Stored Procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697941/performance-implications-of-comments-in-sql-stored-procedures). Related, not a duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think it is good practice

No, it doesn't slow performance. Why would it? Does "someone" have empirical proof or an authoritative article?

Comment: @Laurence Burke: pride goeth before the fall, eh? If so, it means I've learnt something new at least...

Answer (score 4):

It is a great practice to comment the code. Just like coding in a front-end tool, comments are very useful for maintenance & documentation purposes.

Will it slow the "database" down? **Absolutely not.**

Well, let me correct myself.

Code + Inline Comments only come into play when the engine evaluates and prepares the execution plan.

So the compilation may take a very negligible time to *ignore the comments*, but that's about it.

Comment: Extended properties are in a system table somewhere: not related to compile time at all...

Answer (score 0):

Extended properties will not slow the database and there are automated help tools that will harvest the extended properties to produce documentation for you, very useful.